# Updates to reports contained in apps - Do I need to refresh the app?

Tags: powerbi

Say report 'A' is contained in an app. Assume I add a column to a table and republish the report. Do I always need to refresh the app for users to see this new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "table" you mean a *table visualization* that has a new column added, then, yes, you will have to update the app. Any formatting changes to visuals or report layout edits will require the app to be updated. See this [Power BI forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225332/updates-to-reports-contained-in-apps-do-i-need-to-refresh-the-app) for more information.

If you merely updated a column to the *underlying data table*, say, in Power Query and you never added the new column to any visualizations or changed any layouts in your report, you shouldn't have to update the app.